# UIButton constraints issue

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

[image]
The images disappear when I run the simulator.
What kind of constraints do I add to get the images as they are on this picture.

Comment: What constraints have you tried?

Comment: I have added width and height for each of the buttons in the PIN, then given  X and Y  for the top right button and saved, also trailing space to container margin and top space, and for the below 3 buttons "horizontal spacing" and the setting button is "vertical spacing" from the button and then the left and right button leading and trailing space to the container margin.. Nothing works, Only the play button stays in the centre as added vertically and horizontally centre,

Comment: When adding this buttons on the story board, I do not change the simulator size to 4.7 or 5.5 inc, I just take the Inferred size in the Attribute inspector, is  this any problem as I want this too be good for all devices once the constraints are working good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should check apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

For the big play button you could use horizontal and vertical spacing + height and weight. For the three little ones you could use a view to contain the three images and give constraints to the view itself.

Check also what size of device you are working with in your main.storyboard and what device size you are running. Hope it helps

Comment: Ok, try giving the middle one of the three align center to x, height, width, and bottom space. Then use it to give constraints to the other two remaining. For the top right button, as it seems that is align with the bottom right one, you could use either its contratints to help you or set them separately.

Comment: I am using Xcode 7.3 and I do not find an option Centre to X, however I have seen many videos and see that there is an such an option, but when I click the middle small button and drag to either the main view or the play button, or any other direction, I do not get the "centre to X" option, is it not available in Xcode 7.3 ?

Comment: Yes it is, when you control click the button to the view, you should see: Vertical spacing to Bottom-Top and Center Horizontal-vertical in view

Comment: You could also use Stack, Align, Pin and Resolve Tools. It takes more time, but its clearer in the beginning.

Comment: I wish I could show the screen shot, but there is no option to upload picture in comments.. The option options I see are 1. Vertically spacing to the top layout 2. Centre Horizontally in container 3. Equal Width 4. Equal Height 5. Aspect Ratio.

Comment: I tried the Stack, and before I did that I tried the Align and Pin. I guess there is some bug in my Xcode hence I do not get the "centre to x" option,, I do not want to use the stack as I do not get the desired space after I stack the 3 small buttons .

Comment: Option center Horizontally is the same as center to x.. I will upload to gitbhub a project with the constraints.. wait for the link

Comment: Okay. Sure, Thanks

Comment: Thanks mateo, Your code runs good on iPhone 6, but when I try to run the same code on iPhone 5 or other below version the constraints do not on their exact position as they are in iPhone 6.. This is the issue that I am facing. I am trying to add the constraints such that when I run on any other devices, they run in the same way that they do in iPhone 6,, Their position changes from devices to devices. Regards

Comment: They do... I just checked that they modified to have the same proportion and location but in a smaller screen. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0sqVwQ_kPmZQW9ZaGxRcEJQQWM

Comment: Oh! My bad,, the screen was too big, I could only see the play button and the below three buttons, I just scrolled it up and and yes it's working.. Thank you so much @Mateo :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped. No for the moment I don't have any videos. I just created a project in Xcode for your issue.